# FTP is corrupting files since a few days

Tags: ftp, php, notepad++, dreamweaver

Since a few days, every ftp upload I run corrupts files over a certain size, mostly after 400 - 500 lines of code, the file breaks, starts all over from the beginning, and then after a few lines happily resumes the file as normal.

This happens with several ftp clients, notably dreamweaver rapidPhp, and even the command line ftp.

When I upload a file with notepad++ everything seems to work as normal.

I've read several posts which seem to be very similair over the last few days, all of them had no answer as of yet.

EDIT : This happens on 2 diffrent pc's both running windows 8.1 with all the latest updates installed.

Other computers in the office seem unaffected!

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here. After latest Win 8.1 update FTP is failing in exactly the same way as described above. Doing the same with two FTP clients (DW and Filezilla) uploading to two different servers.

Temporary fix here is to use FireFTP in Firefox. The only one I have tried that doesn't have the problem.

Comment: Wow, looks like you nalied it: [FtpOpenFile and InternetWriteFile broken/changed in IE11](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808279/ftpopenfile-and-internetwritefile-broken-changed-in-ie11)

Answer (score 2):

This issue doesn't look software-related to me. It could be the issues with your PC's memory.

I advise you to run a scan with [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso). Leave it overnight if you can. Don't use Windows' built-in memory diagnostic, it never worked for me.

Other causes could include damaged cables, faulty network cards\switches and strong electromagnetic interference (is there any welding going on nearby?).

**UPDATE:** My goodness, it looks like MS did really broke FTP: [FtpOpenFile and InternetWriteFile broken/changed in IE11](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808279/ftpopenfile-and-internetwritefile-broken-changed-in-ie11). Thanks `@ams` for heads up, you've got my upvote and you answer should be accepted.

Comment: I've seen similar issues caused by bad RAM, too. +1 for memtest86.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I'm curious why there is two PC suffering from this issue. My first thought was that the [recent solar flare](http://astronomynow.com/2015/03/12/sun-emits-significant-solar-flare/) damaged their memory chips :).